# Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) When running asp.net page in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

I have some issues running any project in visual studio.

Even with new websites, I get the error in title.

If I visit the website using internet explorer and localhost/project it works. However, I cannot debug it in visual studio

*Any ideas?*

Comment: try the following command in the run dialog 'devenv -resetsettings' .

Comment: didn't work x.x, I have to change the port in the browser to make it work  (Ex  localhost:1000/project    asp Development port: 1002...) visual studio give me another port...